# Expresso Store / Stripe

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, stripe

I have successfully implemented Stripe payments for a saas service, and all is well. Everything has been recorded in store, in my orders area. Looking in the order, I see the details of the transactions, status, reference etc.

So if I am looking at this from the saas point of view, when my next months payment gets pushed in stripe (and it will automatically as a plan billed monthly), is there anything in Expresso store which will record this as an action as part of the same payment, as a transaction on the same order?

I am looking forward - that if someone subscribed to a service, they pay the first month, then the next month they cancel or indeed keep paying, there's some notification of this so I can leave them work away or lock them out accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Store does not support recurring payments or subscriptions, it is currently a [feature request](https://exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) so you can show your interest by voting for it.

If you need something soon you have a  few options you can build an extension that listens for the request from Stripe and then does something in the system. Full extension hook documentation is available [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html). The other option is you could email support@exp-resso.com and see about sponsoring the feature.